# MIPS input string "2147483648", how to return "error: the input number is two big."

Tags: overflow, mips

**Checking MIPS algorithm overflow**
error: .assciiz "error: the input number is two big."
buffer: .space 256

Comment: Is this with MARS or QtSpim?

Comment: hi,  this is QtSpim

Answer (score 1):

For QtSpim, using syscall #5, input integer, there appears to be no way to detect when user input exceeds the 32-bit signed integer range.  No success/failure error code is returned, and the value returned by the syscall, given whatever the user entered, is simply truncated to 32 bits<sup>1</sup>.

If you want to do overflow checking, you'll have accept string data (instead of integer data) from the console and parse the string to integer checking for overflow during that parse.

Such a parse involves doing a multiplication by 10 and an addition for each digit, so with one approach both of those arithmetic operations would need to involve overflow checking.

Importantly, the input to the parse would be a string, and the output would *both a status and a numeric value*, unlike syscall #5, so your program can customize behavior.  The status could indicate success, or failures of various kinds, such as non-digit characters, and overflow.

---

Other approaches to determining the overflow during parse of string to integer are possible, since we know certain facts about decimal digits, such as at most 9 will be added each digit; since we know that 11 total digits (or more) it will overflow (not counting leading zeros, if present).

For example, an alternative approach is to compute the intermediate parse result in 64-bits, then only when converting to 32 bits, check for match of the 32-bit value with the original 64-bit value (match is ok, non-match is overflow).  Since 64 bits can still overflow, counting of total non-zero digits should also be employed with this approach, where anything over 11 would indicate overflow.

---

The other popular MIPS simulator MARS presents a different challenge/opportunity on overflow with syscall #5 — it takes an exception on overflow, but this is not like a Java or C# exception that is easily caught and handled, but instead this is a fault that transfers control to the kernel exception handler in supervisor mode.

Doing something useful with that would be a topic of advanced operation system coursework.  For one, once you write your own kernel exception handler, you have to be prepared to handle all possible processor exceptions, not just overflow; for another you have to differentiate between the overflow condition and the others so you can handle them separately; and lastly, there's no predefined interface for telling the overflowing user-mode program using syscall #5, that this has occurred, and what the user-mode program wants to do about it, so you'd have to provide such mechanism.

---

<sup>1</sup>  These simulators implement effectively useful but an irregular set of system calls — there appears no attempt made to make a complete or well rounded set of syscall operations.  For example, you can read or print an integer or string from/to the console, but can only read or print strings from files — if you want to use files instead of the console with integers, now you have to write your own int to string and vice versa.

Comment: Link to review this question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31610935