# How to I avoid user input integer that overflow in MIPS? Which over the range 2,147,483,647

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

```
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t1, $v0

bgt $t1, 2147483647, outOfRange
```

I already set if greater than 2,147,483,647, then jump to outOfRange, but when I run in mars, the system still show me the error (Invalid integer input) rather than jump to outOfRange and run the instruction I set.

Comment: Your testing is showing that MARS's toy system calls don't allow entering large unsigned integers like `2147483648` (`0x80000000`), unless you only tried with numbers too big even for unsigned 32-bit.  You obviously can't ever have an integer in a 32-bit register that's outside the range for a 32-bit integer, but you could write a program that reads a string from the user (into some large buffer with room for hundreds or thousands of bytes), and checks for overflow as you loop over it converting the ASCII string of decimal digits to a binary integer in a register.

Comment: In a "real" OS like Linux, the actual I/O system calls will only read/write bytes, and converting ASCII strings to `int` or `uint32_t` is something that library functions like `strtol` can do, or you can do it yourself.  But MARS is intended for toy programs to learn the basics, with not much emphasis on writing robust programs that handle I/O errors.  e.g. there's only one return value from `read_int`, no way for it to signal error vs. success.  https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71989891/471129